# how to use Observable method like angular in vue js 3

Tags: vuejs3

I used "'socket-io-client'" in my project. I want receive message in "'vue js'" so i want use Observable method to Observable upcoming message.

Comment: If you want to use Observable, just add RXJS library and use it.

Comment: Your question needs more details. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask